# Using a html class instead of del element to overstrike text

Tags: jquery, html, css

Is it possible to get the text from a paragraph overstriked without using any additional html element such as `del`?

for instance, In this paragraph

```
<p class="sliced-text">
    My text here
</p>
```

I want to my text to be overstriked

How can I implement the `sliced-text` to cut the text in it?

Comment: `$('p:not(.sliced-text)').each(function(){$(this).text($(this.text()).addClass('sliced-text')`

Comment: “Sliced text” apparently refers to overstriking here, the default effect of `del` markup. It is misleading, because in programming, slicing means something completely different.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela sorry I did not know, I edited it to be less missleading

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need any js to do this you can do that just in css like this:

```
.sliced-text{ 
      text-decoration:line-through;
 }
```

#### [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/85VAm/1/)

Comment: I'm not trying to make a script that would change the code from the first to the second, I'm trying to implement the class 'sliced-text' that would show the text in it as sliced

Comment: try the updated one. you can achieve this only with css `text-decoration:line-through;`

Comment: Thank you, this is what I'm looking for. I'm sorry I couldn't explain better the first time.

Comment: The first part of the answer does not even address the question. An accepted answer should contain a correct answer to the question, instead of starting with non-answers.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela my question was a bit vague and Jai answered it as it was. I later edited it to be more precise.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela OP has mentioned the issue. so now i have also updated my answer as per question updated.

Answer (score 0):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mSDRG/2/)**

use `each` to get every dom element  with p tag  then use `.html()`to replace and insert the value

```
 $("p").each(function(){

    $(this).html($(this).text());

}).addClass("sliced-text");
```